# Does $(X⊥Y | z^0)$ for binary-random variable Z implies $(X⊥Y | Z)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have been attempting to reason about this question. 
Does $(X⊥Y | z^0)$ for binary-random variable Z implies $(X⊥Y | Z)$ ?

My intuitive thought is that this is not possible but I would really appreciate it if someone could direct me towards the right path.